# Put the text of a row of a listview in a variable

Tags: android, android-listview

In the application I'm doing, I'm trying to make it do something different depending on the text so I have a code which supposedly retrieves the texto of the row I clicked and then with an if else it tells the program to do something different depending on the code.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    int selectionRowID = (int) this.getSelectedItemId();
    String selectedFileString = this.directoryEntries.get(selectionRowID);
    if (selectedFileString.equals(".")) {
        this.browseToSD();
    } else if(selectedFileString.equals("..")) {
        this.upOneLevel();
    } else {
        File clickedFile = null;
        clickedFile = new File(this.currentDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + this.directoryEntries.get(selectionRowID));
        if(clickedFile != null)
            this.browseTo(clickedFile);
        }
}
```

But it doesn't work, this: "selectedFileString.equals(".")" is always TRUE so it always does browseToSD, but sometimes the text is ".." and most of the times it's something completely different so the app doesn't do what it's suppose to do. I tried to change the code to this:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    ListView lv = getListView();
    ListAdapter list_adapter = lv.getAdapter();
    TextView var_x = (TextView) list_adapter.getView(0,null,null);
    if (var_x.equals(".")) {
        this.browseToSD();
    } else if(var_x.equals("..")) {
        this.upOneLevel();
    } else {
        File clickedFile = null;
        clickedFile = new File(this.currentDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + this.directoryEntries.get(selectionRowID));
        if(clickedFile != null)
            this.browseTo(clickedFile);
        }
}
```

But this doesn't work either, "var_x.equals(".")" and "var_x.equals("..")" are always false. I'm really new to programming with Java and Android so I don't have a clue why it doesn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > "selectedFileString.equals(".")" is always TRUE

It could mean that

```
String selectedFileString = this.directoryEntries.get(selectionRowID)
```

is not working properly fine. That's the first thing you have to review.

> > "var_x.equals(".")" and "var_x.equals("..")" are always false

That's normal. `var_x` is a Widget (TextView), not a String. So it won't be equal ever. Try this:

```
var_x.getText().toString().equals(".")
```

And do this:

```
TextView var_x = (TextView) list_adapter.getView(position,null,null);
```

Comment: I changed to var_x.getText().toString().equals(".") and now it's the same that with selectedFileString.equals("."), it's always TRUE so the the second if else is never evaluated and neither the else... =/ I really haven't got a clue why it doesn't work... both "var_x.getText().toString().equals(".")" and "selectedFileString.equals(".")" seem ok to me

Comment: I edited my answer... it seems you are always getting the first row (you are doing getView(0, null, null)).

Comment: Great! Now it works perfectly. Now, for curiosity, do you or anybody else know why "String selectedFileString = this.directoryEntries.get(selectionRowID)" wasn't working correctly?

Comment: Yes, I know why (I hadn't noticed what you were doing, sorry...). It does not work because `get` expects a position, and you were giving it the row ID, which is different ;)